# Trigger enable TButton with the pick of two (2) dates in TDateTimePickers

Tags: delphi, tdatetimepicker

I have TButton set "not enabled" that should be triggered enabled by the two (2) TDateTimePickers when both dates are picked.

My TDateTimePicker dates are defaulted at a now() date. So, at OnChange, I created the following codes and I couldn't get it right:

```
procedure TfrmPayroll.EnableButton; //my created procedure
begin
  if (dtpFrom.Date = Now()) and
     (dtpTo.Date = Now()) then
  begin
    btnOpen.Enabled := False;
  end
  else
  begin
    btnOpen.Enabled := True;
  end;
```

The result is TButton is enabled even if I only picked one date of the 2 conditions I set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code requires *both* DTPs to be set to `Now` in order to disable the Button, rather than *either* DTP being `Now`.

To fix your existing code, use the `or` operator instead of the `and` operator:

```pascal
procedure TfrmPayroll.EnableButton;
begin
  if (dtpFrom.Date = Now()) or
     (dtpTo.Date = Now()) then
  begin
    btnOpen.Enabled := False;
  end else begin
    btnOpen.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Which can then be simplified if you rewrite the condition to use the `<>` operator instead of the `=` operator:

```pascal
procedure TfrmPayroll.EnableButton;
begin
  btnOpen.Enabled := (dtpFrom.Date <> Now()) and (dtpTo.Date <> Now());
end;
```

And FYI, you should be using `Date()` instead of `Now()` since the `TDateTimePicker.Date` property is not supposed to include time, but `Now()` does. And you should be using a local variable to avoid a race condition if the local clock changes date between the two `Date()` calls:

```pascal
uses
 ..., DateUtils;

procedure TfrmPayroll.EnableButton;
var
  CurrentDate: TDate;
begin
  CurrentDate := Date();
  btnOpen.Enabled := (DateOf(dtpFrom.Date) <> CurrentDate) and (DateOf(dtpTo.Date) <> CurrentDate);
end;
```

Comment: CurrentDate works! Forgot to see that now() includes time. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write:

```
procedure TfrmPayroll.EnableButton; //my created procedure
begin
  btnOpen.Enabled := (dtpFrom.Date <> Now()) and (dtpTo.Date <> Now());
end;
```